# Using Dispatcher.Invoke() in Property Getter

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a property which, upon access, throws an exception with the message: "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

I was trying to work around it by using `Dispatcher.Invoke()` in the getter, but this won't compile due to `Cannot access non-static method 'Invoke' in static context.

```
public override bool Enabled
{
  get
  {
    return Dispatcher.Invoke(() => (ISomethingView) View).ViewModel.Enabled;
    }
  }
}
```

Is there an easier way to make my property thread-safe from within WPF?

Comment: The `Dispatcher` is a property of the type `DispatcherObject`. If you do not inherit from a type that is a DispatcherObject, the compiler will treat the identifier "**Dispatcher**" as the type **System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher** and it would try to find the **static** method Invoke in that type, but it only finds a non-static method, hence error...

Comment: How can I inherit from `DispatcherObject` if I'm already inheriting from `UserControl`. You can't do multiple inheritance in C#.

Comment: Look at the documentation of UserControl. UserControl *is* already a DispatcherObject. But the error *"Cannot access non-static method 'Invoke' in static context"* indicates that the type which declares the public override bool Enabled property given in your example above does not derive from DispatcherObject (or from another type which itself inherits DispatcherObject, including UserControl -- unless, you mix WPF with WinForms and you speak about the WinForms UserControl). However, this should just explain the compiler error, not telling you what to do. For this, look at the answers below.

Comment: I am not mixing WPF and WinForms. I think I may just have an architectural issue. I am loading via DI instances of what I call `IInstallModule`, each concrete of which derives from ModuleBase. I have ModuleBase deriving from DependencyObject too, and it still throws that exception. I use IInstallModule as the entry point to my "plugins. So, I have an object hierarchy like this: IInstallModule->View->ViewModel->Model. All of these objects are singletons in my DI container. The part where the dispatcher may be involved is where I invoke IInstallModule.Install() asynchronously via Tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Type `Dispatcher`, which doesn't have a static `Invoke` method.
You need an `Instance` of the Dispatcher.

Try this:

```
public override bool Enabled
{
  get
  {
    return Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => (ISomethingView) View).ViewModel.Enabled;
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay I am doing that, but now when trying to access the `ViewModel` property, I am getting the same error again in the getter. My getter for `ViewModel` is simply `get { return DataContext as ISomethingViewModel;  }`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your **View** object is the DispatcherObject which does not allow access from another thread. If so, then do something like the following:

```
public override bool Enabled
{
  get
  {
    return View.Dispatcher.Invoke( () => ((ISomethingView)View).ViewModel.Enabled );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher as follows:

```
public override bool Enabled
{
    get
    {
        return System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => { return ((ISomethingView)View).ViewModel.Enabled; });
    }
}
```